# Como listar datos Json con Httpurlconnection en Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rest

Tengo mi web service Rest y necesito poner el json en mi aplicacion de android, por el cual estoy haciendolo en ANDROID STUDIO y ponerlo en un recycler view con cardview.

```html
{
"data": [
{
"not_idnot": 1,
"not_idadmin": "A0001",
"not_autor": "Andrea Carrión",
"not_titulo": "¿Que hacer con las pulgas?",
"not_subtitulo": "mascotas con pulgas",
"not_articulo": "Cuando el perro no logra superar la amenaza y se sigue sintiendo acorralado, lo más probable es que suba un escalón más...",
"not_image": "https://img.elcomercio.pe/files/article_content_ec_fotos/uploads/2018/06/01/5b11768068677.jpeg",
"not_datecreated": "14-06-2018 10:52:21",
"not_estado": "A"
}
}
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Lo puedes realizar mediante un asyntask ...

Comment: Lo que deseo es saber el código para llamarlo de la web service con el método GET y enviarlo en un arraylist

Comment: ¿Cual es el objeto donde vas a almacenar esta información? ¿Este json que agregas es la respuesta?